# How to get clicked input id in Blazor

Tags: asp.net-core, html-table, datatable, blazor

I'm trying to make an editable table component with Blazor. Is there the easiest way to get a changed input id with value?

The table should have an add and update functionality for columns, and rows.Im trying to do it with DataTable:

```
    DataTable dt = new DataTable();
    for (int columns = 0; columns < 4; columns++)
    {
        dt.Columns.Add($"col{columns}");
    }

    for (int rows = 0; rows < 6; rows++)
    {
        DataRow row = dt.NewRow();
        for (int columns = 0; columns < 4; columns++)
        {
            row[columns] = $"row{rows} value{columns}";
        }
        dt.Rows.Add(row);
    }
```

I'm still trying to find a best way to create this table. Table looks like this:

```
 <table class="table table-bordered table-responsive-md table-striped text-center">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    @foreach (DataColumn column in dt.Columns)
                    {
                        <th class="text-center">@column.ColumnName</th>
                    }

                    <th class="text-center">Remove</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                @for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
                {
                    <tr>
                        @for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows[i].ItemArray.Count(); j++)
                        {
                            <td class="pt-3-half"> <input id="j" @onclick="() => ClickedCellPosition(j, i)" type="text" name="name" value=" @dt.Rows[i][j]" /> </td>
                        }
                        <td>
                            <span class="table-remove">
                                <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger btn-rounded btn-sm my-0">
                                    Remove
                                </button>
                            </span>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                }
            </tbody>
        </table>
```

I know that this is not the best way, but I'm trying to understand how is work blazor.
At first, I should have only 1 input AddColum and AddRow for creating columns, and rows. In the end, there can be a table with many rows and columns.
And in the end, I should save the whole data in this way:
[image]

Comment: Some code might help to understand what you want. And what `id` are you after, the HTML id ?  For what purpose?

Comment: I don't know what you're trying to archive, but i guess you're looking for data binding, so I'll just add a link to the [Documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/blazor/components/data-binding?view=aspnetcore-6.0)